# how to insert rows to a table with foreign key which is auto incremented without multiple queries to the parent table

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have a "metrics" parent table and a "key-values" child table.

each row in `metrics` could have associated key-values to be stored in the "key-values" table (the number of key-values isn't bound, could be 0 or more)

the metrics rows ids are autoincremented and the timestamps generated by the sqlite, (since allowing multiple metrics at the same instance)

for example I thought of a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
    );

CREATE TABLE keyvalues(
    key TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    metric_id INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT fk_keyval
      FOREIGN KEY(metric_id) 
      REFERENCES metrics(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The `metric id` primary key is `auto-incremented` and the `timestamp` is generated by the sqlite, I'm not sure how to go about inserting rows to both the metrics table and the associated `keyvalues` table at the same time.

my internal API looks along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
Metric {
  name: String,
  keyvals: Map<String,String>
}


func count_metric(metric: Metric) {
  sqlite.execute("insert into metrics(name) value(metric.name)");
// now how to go about inserting to the `keyvalues` table?
   foreach (key,value) in metric.keyvals {
       sqlite.execute("insert into keyvalues(key,value,metric_id) values(?,?,?)" , key , value , "rowid") // how do I get the row id efficiantly and ensure correctness if multiple inserts occur conccurently?
   }

}
```

Do I have to insert first to the metrics table, query it for the last row id and then go about inserting to the keyvalues table the appropriate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`last_insert_rowid()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid):

```
insert into metrics(name) values(?);
insert into keyvalues(key, value, metric_id) values(?, ?, last_insert_rowid());
```

Comment: there is a propblem with this approach when doing a batch , since the last_insert_row_id() returns the id of the foreign key table.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO metrics(name) VALUES ('name1');
INSERT INTO properties VALUES('f2', 'v2', last_insert_rowid());
INSERT INTO properties VALUES('f3', 'v3', last_insert_rowid());
COMMIT;
```